# how to check if an object exists in jq

Tags: json, key, jq, missing-data

I've the following Json

```
{
"_shards": {
    "failed": 0
}, 
"hits": {
    "hits": [
        {
            "_id": "P16296", 
            "_source": {
                "category": {
                    "all_categories": [
                        {
                            "id": 76, 
                            "name": "Souris" 
                        }
                    ], 
                    "master_category": {
                        "id": 76, 
                        "name": "Souris" 
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id": "P749525", 
            "_source": {
                "category": {
                    "all_categories": [
                        {
                            "id": 1301, 
                            "name": "Produits abim\u00e9s", 
                        }
                    ], 
                    "master_category": []
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Hi want to get the id and the master cat id so I'm doing this

```
cat test2.json | jq -c '.hits.hits[]|{products_ids: ._id, cat_id: ._source.category.master_category.id}'
```

But unfortunately I get an error :
jq: error (at :48): Cannot index array with string "id"

That's because for the second hit, there's no .source.category.master_category.id

I trye to test it with if then else and .source.category.master_category.id>0 but there's still teh error. So I need to test if .source.category.master_category.id but I can't find how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `?` suffix operator, e.g.

```
.hits.hits[]
| { products_ids: ._id,
    cat_id: ._source.category.master_category.id? }
```

or if you want to be more inclusive:

```
.hits.hits[]
| { products_ids: ._id,
    cat_id: (._source.category.master_category.id? // null ) }
```

You could also check whether a property exists using `has/1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peak, the second one is the most helpful to me because I need all the products_ids entries. First one, would not spit out the second product.